# sql order without orderitems doesnt give a result

Tags: sql, oracle

My desired result is the information about one order. When my order has some orderitems then the folowing query works fine, but as soon as it is an empty order it doesn't give any info. For example my orderid = 5 and this one does not have any items yet. I use the orderitems to calculate the total cost of the order. how do i get my information when there isnt an orderitem? This is my Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  u.firstname|| ' ' || u.lastname, 
  TO_CHAR(o.date,'DD-MON-YY HH24:mm'),
  (SELECT SUM(oItem.amount * oItem.pricewhenordered) FROM ORDERITEM oItem WHERE 
  oItem.ORDERID=o.ID), 
  (case o.employeeid
    when null then '-'
    else (SELECT us.firstname|| ' ' || us.lastname FROM user us WHERE 
    id=o.employeeid)
  END), 
  o.status
FROM order o, orderitem oItem, user u
WHERE o.userid = u.id
AND o.id = oItem.orderid
AND o.id = 5;
```

TABLES
`order`
id,
userid,
date,
status,
employeeid

`orderitem`
orderid,
productid,
amount,
pricewhenordered

`user`
id,
username,
password,
firstname,
lastname,
usertypeid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually using the ORDERITEM (oitem) table in your main query; just leave it out:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  u.firstname|| ' ' || u.lastname, 
  TO_CHAR(o.date,'DD-MON-YY HH24:mm'),
  (SELECT SUM(oItem.amount * oItem.pricewhenordered) 
     FROM ORDERITEM oItem 
    WHERE oItem.ORDERID=o.ID), 
  (case o.employeeid
        when null 
        then '-'
        else (SELECT us.firstname|| ' ' || us.lastname 
                FROM user us 
               WHERE id=o.employeeid)
        END), 
  o.status
FROM 
    order o, user u
WHERE 
    o.userid = u.id
    AND o.id = 5;
```

Comment: If you don't need any more information about the items (And my guess is you don't) then this is preferable to my answer.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Not very smart of my to overlook the useless orderitem in main query. Thx for the quick and good reply:)

Answer (score 1):

Being explicit about your joins and using a LEFT join in case of no items should do the job.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  u.firstname|| ' ' || u.lastname, 
  TO_CHAR(o.date,'DD-MON-YY HH24:mm'),
  (SELECT SUM(oItem.amount * oItem.pricewhenordered) FROM ORDERITEM oItem WHERE 
  oItem.ORDERID=o.ID), 
  (case o.employeeid
    when null then '-'
    else (SELECT us.firstname|| ' ' || us.lastname FROM user us WHERE 
    id=o.employeeid)
  END), 
  o.status
FROM order o
LEFT OUTER JOIN orderitem oItem ON  o.id = oItem.orderid
INNER JOIN user u ON o.userid = u.id
WHERE o.id = 5;
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. I'm going to go with the answer of Joe on this one, but thank you for your time:)